# Securely Store API Key in Android

Tags: android, security, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I'm using `openAI` directly in my ***Android Kotlin App*** for chatting feature instead of having a custom server that stores the `ApiKey` and communicates with `openAI`, then return the response in an `endpoint` or `API`.

Im using `JNI` for storing the key in a `.c` file and returning it to my Kotlin code. Is this secure? Or what is the better approach to store **API Keys**.

src/main/java/vvv.altug.dreamgpt/NativeLibWrapper

```
package vvv.altug.dreamgpt

class NativeLibWrapper {
    companion object {
        init {
            System.loadLibrary("native-lib")
        }

        @JvmStatic
        external fun getApiKey(): String
    }
}
```

app/jni/native-lib.c

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_vvv_altug_dreamgpt_NativeLibWrapper_getApiKey(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,
                                "sk-XXXXXXXXXkeyXXXXXXXXX");
}
```

ViewModel:

```
val apiKey = NativeLibWrapper.getApiKey()
```

Comment: with minifyEnabled true and default proguard rules applied.

Comment: Anything on device can be decompiled. Calling from Android client just means that once your key is stolen there is no way for you to stop it other than terminating the OpenAI key along with your valid authorized client app.

Comment: If the android app can get at your API key, so can a dedicated person. Do not do this.

Answer (score 1):

Do not do this. No matter how convoluted and complex you make the process of getting the API key, at some point it will sit in memory. Anyone can rebuild your APK in debugging mode and just put a breakpoint at the right point in your program.

At a bare minimum, write a stupid simple request forwarder in AWS lambda or Azure Functions (or fly.io or ...) and have your application talk to *that*. That way you can set up alerts for when (not if) people discover your endpoint is more or less a free to use OpenAI endpoint.

Comment: The issue I'm facing is that I need to stimulate the "typing" response just like we experience on chatGpt website. I've achieved that before using a django server and ServerSentEvents. Do you happen to know if that can be achieved using firebase functions or the AWS/Azure solutions you mentioned?

Comment: ... break the response into random chunks of 1-10 words at a time and show them with a small delay? That is a completely different question (and a very silly reason to do this)

Comment: client budget & expectations make you do silly things.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to complicate your life with calls to a remote WS ? Android supports  natively Encryption/Decryption using the most common algorithms and it's quite simple (see: [Android's crypto API](https://developer.android.com/privacy-and-security/cryptography)). Even if you save the key on a remote server you'll have to download it and it would be vulnerable also in that case once you start using it when you send requests to OpenAI's endpoints (do not forget that you must specify the key at every call to OpenAI's API). At least your key is so important that if hacked it will cause enormous global problems or you think that someone is so eager to steal your key (that means 0.00x% of the programmers on this planet), just encrypt it using the cryptography features of Android. Worst case scenario, you delete it from OpenAI's website and create a new one. You can have more keys bound to your subscription. If the chat app is to be used by other users, you could ask them to enter a customized key (that they can get like you from OpenAI by paying the subscription) when they setup the application. I mean, there are several good solutions to work around your problem without causing yourself headaches.

Comment: The problem of embedding the key in the application is that deleting it means a broken app and angry users. (or client)  The point of going through a remote server is that the key is kept there and never exposed to the client. This completely prevents the unsolvable problem OP is trying to solve

Comment: I understand that. But having to implement the storage logic and functions on Azure or Amazons WS ... or whatever to safe a key it looks to me a little too much effort, at least if it is about a normal chat app and not something very secretive. In the end we are speaking about an API Key used to access OpenAI endpoints not a bank account. It is true that someone could steal it and use your OpenAI credit to access the most advanced features of ChatGPT (we are speaking about 30-60 USD), but it looks a big deal for such a limited gain.

Comment: What do you think will happen when OpenAI finds that this API key is discovered sitting in the APK and used by thousands of people? Likewise, what if the API key ever needs to be rotated? Spending "a little too much effort" once makes sure that whatever service OP is tasked to implement keeps working. It would be unethical to create something that is guaranteed to stop working at some point in the near future. I hope OP factored the cost of (mostly) building that small proxy into their project.

Comment: @Botje the API Key is unique and personal and issued by paying a monthly fee. What you do with your KEY is your business not OpenAI's. When you have depleted the credit, the requests to ChatGPT endpoints will be rejected. I don't think they mind where you put your key. It's a design choice, as said before, if the app is intended for high risk purposes or the leak of it could endanger anybody then I would consider more sophisticated means of hiding it as you suggest. But in this particular case, in my opinion (that is by no means the best out there), cryptography could be the way to go.

Comment: Using a personal ChatGPT key in an application would fall under "distribute any of our Services" which is prohibited by the terms of use for ChatGPT. If OP is using a business account -- which does allow this -- they are billed by the token.

Comment: Yes, that's true, in fact I didn't say you must display the API key on the home screen of the app, but you cannot prevent hacking. OpenAI cannot blame you because you encrypted the key and a smart guy succeeded to hack it. And you are right, when I said " ...What you do with your KEY is your business not OpenAI's..." it was an overstatement, but the general idea I wanted to express with stays. Then is up to abdulwasey20 decide what to do next. Thank you anyway for your valuable opinion.